# Hibernate DTO Projections N+1 queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Just experimented an interesting fact while using Hibernate & Spring Data JPA.
I have the following setup DTO and Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClassDto {
     private String id;
     private String name;

      public ClassDto(Entity e) {
         this.id = e.id;
        this.name = e.name;
      }

      public ClassDto(String id, String name) {
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
      }
}

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class Entity {
     @Id String id;
     String name;
}
```

Why this query got executed N+1 times.

```
select new org.xyz.ClassDto(e) from Entity e
```

While this one with entity destructured just once

```
select new org.xyz.ClassDto(e.id, e.name) from Entity e
```

I want only a logical explanation about how things works underground.

**LATER EDIT** after comments, testable code (already inserted 3 entries in table):

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
public class EntityA {

    @Id Long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

@Setter
@Getter
public class ClassDto {

    Long id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public ClassDto(Long id,
                    String firstName,
                    String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public ClassDto(EntityA entityA) {
        this.id = entityA.id;
        this.firstName = entityA.firstName;
        this.lastName = entityA.lastName;
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("---- WITH N+1 -----");
        var resultList1 = entityManager.createQuery("" +
                "select new com.example.demo.ClassDto(e) " +
                "from EntityA e").getResultList();
        System.out.println(resultList1.toString());

        System.out.println("---- WITHOUT N+1 -----");
        var resultList2 = entityManager.createQuery("" +
                "select new com.example.demo.ClassDto(e.id, e.firstName, e.lastName) " +
                "from EntityA e").getResultList();
        System.out.println(resultList2.toString());
    }
}


-----
OUTPUT:
---- WITH N+1 -----
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as col_0_0_ from test.entitya entitya0_
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_, entitya0_.first_name as first_na2_0_0_, entitya0_.last_name as last_nam3_0_0_ from test.entitya entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_, entitya0_.first_name as first_na2_0_0_, entitya0_.last_name as last_nam3_0_0_ from test.entitya entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_0_, entitya0_.first_name as first_na2_0_0_, entitya0_.last_name as last_nam3_0_0_ from test.entitya entitya0_ where entitya0_.id=?
[com.example.demo.ClassDto@63485d7, com.example.demo.ClassDto@23ea8830, com.example.demo.ClassDto@59a09be]
---- WITHOUT N+1 -----
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as col_0_0_, entitya0_.first_name as col_1_0_, entitya0_.last_name as col_2_0_ from test.entitya entitya0_
[com.example.demo.ClassDto@4416e18d, com.example.demo.ClassDto@5dfc2a4, com.example.demo.ClassDto@3120495d]
```

Thanks

Comment: I actually doubt it happens with this code and in your real code you have a lazy property/field in there.

Comment: Nothing like that, I'm sure of that, it was the first thing which I checked before asking here.

Comment: Well the code you posted here I doubt it would show that so please provide some real code, with configuration and a test. That being said the second one is also the preferred one if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Just added testable code. Waiting for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using a query like this:

```
select new org.xyz.ClassDto(e.toManyAssociation) from Entity e
```

In this case, Hibernate will pass in a proxy instead of a fully initialized entity, so when you access the data of that object in the constructor, Hibernate will lazy load the object. You can solve that by joining the association and passing the join alias instead.

I think you might be interested in [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) though.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Entity.class)
public interface ClassDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ClassDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ClassDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ClassDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!